# Decode a dictionary in json using Swift 5 and Codable

Tags: json, swift, parsing, codable

I'm trying to decode data in JSON( where the value objects in the dictionary are not similar) using Swift 5.2 and Codable, any suggestion for doing this where the code will be easily expandable for adding more food items in the json?

```
{
    "main courses": [
        {
            "date availabiliy": "June 12, 2017 1:23:31 PM",
            "price": 10.29,
            "name": "chicken_rice",
            "receipe": "page 16"
        },
        {
            "date availabiliy": "July 12, 2017 1:23:31 PM",
            "price": 12.29,
            "name": "beef_rice",
            "receipe": "page 5"
        },
        {
           "date availabiliy": "July 12, 2017 1:23:31 PM",
            "price": 14.49,
            "name": "California roll",
            "receipe": "page 25"
        }
    ],
    "desserts": [
        {
            "popularity": 75,
            "calory": "high",
            "name": "Avacado, Basil,and cream",
            "date availabiliy": "July 12, 2017 1:23:31 PM",
            "taste": "sweet",
        },
        {
           "popularity": 39,
            "calory": "med",
            "name": "ice cream",
            "date availabiliy": "July 22, 2017 1:23:31 PM",
            "taste": "sweet",
        },
    ],
}
```

Thank you!
Cam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this model created from https://app.quicktype.io/

```
import Foundation

// MARK: - Response
struct Response: Codable {
    let mainCourses: [MainCourse]
    let desserts: [Dessert]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case mainCourses = "main courses"
        case desserts = "desserts"
    }
}

// MARK: - Dessert
struct Dessert: Codable {
    let popularity: Int
    let calory, name, dateAvailabiliy, taste: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case popularity, calory, name
        case dateAvailabiliy = "date availabiliy"
        case taste
    }
}

// MARK: - MainCourse
struct MainCourse: Codable {
    let dateAvailabiliy: String
    let price: Double
    let name, receipe: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case dateAvailabiliy = "date availabiliy"
        case price, name, receipe
    }
}
```

use it like

```
let response = try? newJSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: jsonData)
```

Comment: @Cam This answer was generated with https://app.quicktype.io/ have a look at it

Comment: Oh, you're right. Thank you for informing me Eric

Comment: @EricAya sorry i don't describe about that let me update.